# Do the generators of the subfields of a field extension $K$ "generate" $K$ in a linear sense?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

This is kind of a two-parter, I am reading this proof that has some steps that suggest that this true:

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\theta)$ with $\mathbb{Q} \subset K$ Galois, and $\mathbb{Q(\theta_1)}, \mathbb{Q(\theta_2)},...... \mathbb{Q(\theta_n)}$ be all the subfields of $K$.

1. Is $K$ $\mathbb{Q}$-linearly generated by $\theta_1,..\theta_n$? (i.e for every $x \in K$, $x$ can be expressed as $x=a_1\theta_1+...+a_n\theta_n$ for $a_i \in \mathbb{Q}$)
2. Is there a relation between the linear expression above given and $\theta$'s conjugates? (i.e if $x=a_1\theta_1+...+a_n\theta_n$, can I find $x'$ ($x$ first conjugate) using that equation?)

Now I am guessing the first can be explained by absurd reasoning and generating another subfield.
The second seems logical, since each $\mathbb{Q}(\theta_i)$ is directly associated to a conjugate of $\theta$ by Galois. But I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Do you assume that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois?

Comment: Let $K$ be any cubic extension of $\mathbb Q$. Then there are exactly two subfields of $K$, but $K$ is 3-dimensional over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, forgot to put that in.

Answer (score 1):

If $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is cyclic, with Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then there are as many subfields of $K$ as there are divisors of $n$. Of course unless $n\leqslant 2$ this number is strictly less than $n$, so generators of subfields cannot form a linear basis of $K$, since the dimension of $K$ is $n$.

Comment: Ok, i see where you are going. I think my flaw was assuming that the only elements in the Galois group were cyclic generated by the conjugate permutations.

Comment: When you talk about the dimension of $K$, do you mean degree?

Comment: Yes, it is the same thing, the degree of an extension is by definition its dimension as a vector space on the base field. Since I was referring to a specifically linear property I used the word "dimension", but "degree" works just as well.

Comment: I think your example is not a Galois extension, because if you are Galois, then the order of your Galois group is equal to the degree of your extension.

Comment: Of course. But it turns out $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ has $n$ elements, so there is no contradiction. A cyclic extension is Galois by definition.